# extract sub-string in T-SQL based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have address in sql column which also contain postcode i.e. as following format

```
10 westminister way Road, London (NW10 5NQ)
```

but not all record may have postcode which in case will be like

```
 10 westminister way Road, London
```

I need to extract post from string which is working fine except following character throw error if postcode doesn't exist which i believe i need to use contain but not sure how to modify existing code to do so

```
select 
,REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([address]),2, CHARINDEX('(', REVERSE([address]))-2)) PostCode
,CHARINDEX('(', REVERSE([address]))-2 indexDetail
```

my question is how to use contain or if condition so

```
 if(CHARINDEX('(', REVERSE([address])) = true then proceed with substring
 else ignore record
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `IIF`. This will grab everything in the parentheses, regardless of how long the postal code is. I'm not sure if they vary in the UK.

```
declare @table table ([address] varchar(256))
insert into @table
values
('10 westminister way Road, London (NW10 5NQ)'),
('10 westminister way Road, London')

select
    [address],
    PostCode = iif(charindex('(',[address]) > 1, substring([address],charindex('(',[address]),charindex(')',[address])),''),
    PostalNoParan = iif(charindex('(',[address]) > 1, replace(replace(substring([address],charindex('(',[address]),charindex(')',[address])),'(',''),')',''),'')
from @table
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
  [address], 
  PostalCode = SUBSTRING([address], NULLIF(charindex('(',[address]),0), 256) 
FROM @table;
```

If you need an empty string instead of `NULL`:

```
SELECT 
  [address], 
  PostalCode = COALESCE(SUBSTRING([address], NULLIF(charindex('(',[address]),0), 256),'') 
FROM @table;
```

Comment: Much shorter than mine, reversing the exception for the rule. SMRT

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
select (case when address like '% (%)'
             then left(right(address, 9), 8)
        end) as postcode
```